# Slick Slider (v1.8.0) issue with non-infinite autoplay

Tags: slick.js

This has been a real head-scratcher. Im using Slick v1.8.0 with jQuery 2.1.3.

I have infinite set to false, and showing and advancing 3 slides at a time. If the slider has 10 or fewer slides, the slider slides left to reveal next slides, advances through the slides once, hits the end, and stops. However, if I add 1 slide, when the slider hits the end (slide 11 is showing), the slider then switches directions when it hits the end and advances back down through the slides to the beginning, where it stops.

```
$(".slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  pauseOnHover: false,
});
$(".slider").slick('slickPlay');
```

Example with 10 slides: http://jsfiddle.net/adambundy/26nyw1ac/
11 slides: http://jsfiddle.net/adambundy/txpj96ub/

The actual issue I have been hammering on is that my case has 11 slides, so I assumed the 'seesaw' was the intended functionality. What I've been wrestling with is that when it comes back to the beginning after switching directions, it seems to 'break' and gets stuck on slide 1. The event 'beforeChange' stops triggering (though afterChange keeps being triggered on the delay interval), and the slider is basically paused. I'd prefer it reverse directions again and continue advancing.

What works, though I'd like to figure out a simpler fix, is to detect when the slider is back to the beginning (via afterChange), and destroy, then re-init the slider and play it.